# Roracle query Chinese garbled

Tags: r

Roracle query results but Chinese characters are garbled:

```
query <- "SELECT CONDITION_NAME7  FROM BI_CONDITION where rownum = 1"
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, query, ncharset = "UTF-8")
# Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
#   ORA-00904: "CONDITION_NAME7": ��ʶ����Ч

query <- "SELECT CONDITION_NAME  FROM BI_CONDITION where rownum = 1"
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, query, ncharset = "UTF-8")

data <- dbFetch(result)
print(data)
#                                CONDITION_NAME
# 1 һ\xbc\xbe\xb6\xc8\xc6\xdaĩ\xd7ʲ\xfa\xd7ܶ\xee
```

I set system environment variable
NLS_LANG=SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.ZHS16GBK but this did not work.